# RabbitMQ Camel Consumer Error - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

New to Camel RabbitMQ. Wrote a simple RabbitMQ consumer with Apache Camel.

```
onException(StateException.class).log(LoggingLevel.WARN,"WarnMessage = Error on ID and Status ${body}.")
            .asyncDelayedRedelivery().redeliveryDelay(5000).maximumRedeliveries(1)
            .setHeader(RabbitMQConstants.REQUEUE, constant(true))
            .handled(true)
            .setFaultBody(constant(true));

from(STATE__Q_URL).delay(200).log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,"Incoming Body is --> ${body}")
          /*  .wireTap("direct:logtofile")*/.to("invokeManager")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message = Completed for ${body}");
```

`invokeManager` currently makes a simple rest call after popping out a value from Queue. **It works fine for around 100 message and starts throwing this error**

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.flush(SocketFrameHandler.java:177) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.flush(AMQConnection.java:559) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:127) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:396) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:378) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingRpc(AMQChannel.java:313) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:601) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:534) ~[amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.StrictExceptionHandler.handleChannelKiller(StrictExceptionHandler.java:68) [amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.StrictExceptionHandler.handleConsumerException(StrictExceptionHandler.java:58) [amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:154) [amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:100) [amqp-client-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]

2018-02-25 18:06:17.551  WARN 4155 --- [0.42.31.42:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: im having same problem.. did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Robbo_UK yes i figured out the problem was with the buffer size of consumer. You need to set a few fields inorder to fix this issue

```
            +"&prefetchEnabled=true"
            +"&prefetchCount=100"
            +"&threadPoolSize="100"
            +"&channelPoolMaxSize="100"
```

I randomly copied the values from my code. This will solve your issues.

So this will restrict the number of messages pushed to the consumer and will prevent the buffer Overflow.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  My understanding is that the issue occurs because of overloading too much data at once.  I noticed how it was saying all the messages were consumed but not ack.  one more question is threadPoolSize 100 a bit large?

Comment: @Robbo_UK , you are right, it pushes all it can in one shot and fills the consumer buffer so we need to restrict what it is pushing to consumer. On my end each thread writes it into a DB and ACK it,a very simple write operation and i feel it handles 100 very smooth.

At its crux, look at the memory foot print of each thread and if the thread doesn't churn too much memory, we are good. 

At the end you can also try running a profiler if you are seeing issues. I feel it is going to be fine with 100.